# linux wake_up_interruptible() having no effect

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver, device

I am writing a "sleepy" device driver for an Operating Systems class.

The way it works is, the user accesses the device via `read()`/`write()`.
When the user writes to the device like so: `write(fd, &wait, size)`, the device is put to sleep for the amount of time in seconds of the value of `wait`. If the wait time expires then driver's write method returns 0 and the program finishes. But if the user reads from the driver while a process is sleeping on a wait queue, then the driver's write method returns immediately with the number of seconds the sleeping process had left to wait before the timeout would have occurred on its own.

Another catch is that 10 instances of the device are created, and each of the 10 devices must be independent of each other. So a read to device 1 must only wake up sleeping processes on device 1.

Much code has been provided, and I have been charged with the task of mainly writing the `read()` and `write()` methods for the driver.

The way I have tried to solve the problem of keeping the devices independent of each other is to include two global static arrays of size 10. One of type `wait_head_queue_t`, and one of type `Int`(Bool flags). Both of these arrays are initialized once when I open the device via `open()`. The problem is that when I call `wake_up_interruptible()`, nothing happens, and the program terminates upon timeout. Here is my write method:

```
ssize_t sleepy_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos){
struct sleepy_dev *dev = (struct sleepy_dev *)filp->private_data;

ssize_t retval = 0;
int mem_to_be_copied = 0;

if (mutex_lock_killable(&dev->sleepy_mutex))  
{ 
    return -EINTR; 
}

// check size
if(count != 4)  // user must provide 4 byte Int
{
    return EINVAL; // = 22
}
//  else if the user provided valid sized input...
else
{
      if((mem_to_be_copied = copy_from_user(&long_buff[0], buf, count))) 
      { 
        return -EFAULT; 
      }

      // check for negative wait time entered by user
      if(long_buff[0] > -1)// "long_buff[]"is global,for now only holds 1 value
      {
        proc_read_flags[MINOR(dev->cdev.dev)] = 0;  //****** flag array
        retval = wait_event_interruptible_timeout(wqs[MINOR(dev->cdev.dev)],   proc_read_flags[MINOR(dev->cdev.dev)] == 1, long_buff[0] * HZ) / HZ;
        proc_read_flags[MINOR(dev->cdev.dev)] = 0; // MINOR numbers for each
                                    // device correspond to array indices 
                                       // devices 0 - 9
                                         // "wqs" is array of wait queues
      }
      else
      {
         printk(KERN_INFO "user entered negative value for sleep time\n");
      }
}

mutex_unlock(&dev->sleepy_mutex);
return retval;}
```

Unlike the many examples on this topic, I am switching the flag back to zero immediately before the call to `wait_event_interruptible_timeout()` because flag values seem to be lingering between subsequent runs of the program. Here is the code for my read method:

```
 ssize_t sleepy_read(struct file *filp, char __user *buf, size_t count, 
        loff_t *f_pos){

 struct sleepy_dev *dev = (struct sleepy_dev *)filp->private_data;
 ssize_t retval = 0;

 if (mutex_lock_killable(&dev->sleepy_mutex))
     return -EINTR;

 // switch the flag
 proc_read_flags[MINOR(dev->cdev.dev)] = 1; // again device minor numbers
                                             // correspond to array indices 

 // TODO:   this is not waking up the process in write!
 // wake up the queue
 wake_up_interruptible(&wqs[MINOR(dev->cdev.dev)]);

 mutex_unlock(&dev->sleepy_mutex);

return retval;}
```

The way I am trying to test the program is to have two main.c's, one for writing to the device and one for reading from the device, and I just `./a.out` them in separate consoles in my ubuntu installation in Virtual Box. Another thing, the way it is set up now, neither the writing or reading `a.outs` return until timeout occurs. I apologize for the spotty formatting of the code. I'm not sure exactly what is going on here, so any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: Did you confirmed  wake_up_interruptible(&wqs[MINOR(dev->cdev.dev)])  is calling before your time out interval is reached?

Comment: jjm, you're right, wake_up_interruptible is not called until after timeout.

Answer (score 2):

Your write method hold *sleepy_mutex* while wait event. So read method waits on `mutex_lock_killable(&dev->sleepy_mutex)` while the mutex become unlocked by the writer. It is occured only when writer's timeout exceeds, and write method returns. It is the behaviour you observe.

Usually, wait_event* is executed outside of any critical section. That can be achieved by using *_lock*-suffixed variants of such macros, or simply wrapping *cond* argument of such macros with spinlock acquire/release pair:

```
int check_cond()
{
    int res;
    spin_lock(&lock);
    res = <cond>;
    spin_unlock(&lock);
    return res;
}
...
    wait_event_interruptible(&wq, check_cond());
```

Unfortunately, *wait_event*-family macros cannot be used, when condition checking should be protected with a mutex. In that case, you can use wait_woken() function with manual condition checking code. Or rewrite your code without needs of mutex lock/unlock around condition checking.

For achive "reader wake writer, if it is sleep" functionality, you can adopt code from that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29765695/3440745.

Writer code:

```
    //Declare local variable at the beginning of the function
    int cflag;
    ...
    // Outside of any critical section(after mutex_unlock())
    cflag = proc_read_flags[MINOR(dev->cdev.dev)];
    wait_event_interruptible_timeout(&wqs[MINOR(dev->cdev.dev)],
        proc_read_flags[MINOR(dev->cdev.dev)] != cflag, long_buff[0]*HZ);
```

Reader code:

```
    // Mutex holding protects this flag's increment from concurrent one.
    proc_read_flags[MINOR(dev->cdev.dev)]++;
    wake_up_interruptible_all(&wqs[MINOR(dev->cdev.dev)]);
```